# Callback function doesn't work Highcharts PhantomJS

Tags: highcharts, callback, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to save the charts in my server, but the callback function doesn't work.

```
phantomjs JS/highcharts-convert.js -infile temp/test.js -outfile temp/chart.png -globaloptions temp/test2.js -callback temp/call.js
```

The content in call.js is:

```
function() {
    console.log('kamehameha');
}
```

Everything works great, except the callback.

Comment: Have you tried to use example from the [docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside) ? Instead of `console.log('..')`.

Comment: Yes, I did, but what was it supposed to do? Nothing has happened either.

Comment: It looks like you are using outdated version of highcharts-convert.js or Highcharts/Highstock files. Make sure you have latest version (at least 4.x/2.x).

Comment: I am using Highstock JS v2.0.3 and  highcharts-convert 2.0.1, even after updating to Highstock JS v2.1.3 it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with latest version of exporting server and Highstock. Files:

- call.js:

  ```
  function(chart) {chart.renderer.arc(200, 150, 100, 50, -Math.PI, 0).attr({fill : '#FCFFC5',stroke : 'black','stroke-width' : 1}).add();}
  ```
- test.js:

  ```
  {xAxis: {categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}]}
  ```
- test2.js:

  ```
  { legend: { enabled: false } }
  ```

And works fine, output from the console:

```
Highcharts.options.parsed
Highcharts.cb.parsed
Highcharts.globalOptions.parsed
Highcharts.customCode.parsed
temp/chart.png
```

Generated image: 
[image]

**EDIT:** 
Tested with that callback:

```
 function(chart) {console.log("kamehameha"); chart.renderer.arc(200, 150, 100, 50, -Math.PI, 0).attr({fill : '#FCFFC5',stroke : 'black','stroke-width' : 1}).add();}
```

And output:

```
Highcharts.options.parsed
Highcharts.cb.parsed
Highcharts.globalOptions.parsed
Highcharts.customCode.parsed
kamehameha
temp/chart.png
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce your example, although my situation is that I want to execute some JS (document.getElementById("FramePrincipal").style.display = "";) in the callback function, so I started using a simple console.log, but neither (console.log and style.display) worked .

Comment: See my edit about `console.log()`. Where do you have "FramePrincipal" in your chart? I think it's quite important for your question.. In general I suggest to add to question required chart options and required callback. As you can see in my examples -> callback itself works perfectly fine.

Comment: Well, your suggestions helped me to make callback work, although it seems that I can't use it to call generic JS commands, only chart options.

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve? Remember, when exporting, code is executed in the sandboxed phantomJS, and is limited to the SVG only.

Comment: Yes, now it makes sense. Anyway, the problem described in the question itself got solved.  Thank you.